# Por que o Python permite sobrescrever o valor de False e True?

Tags: python

Estou estudando `Python` e, nesses estudos acabei me deparando com algo curioso.

```
> False = True
#Imprime: True

> print(False)
#Imprime: True

> False = bool(0)
> print(False)
#Imprime: False
```

Ou seja, consegui reescrever o valor de `False` dando a ele o valor de `True`.

Em linguagens como `javascript` ou `PHP` não é possível fazer essa reatribuição, pelo fato de `False` se tratar de um construtor da linguagem ou até mesmo uma constante.

Por que no `Python` é possível fazer isso? Como é tratado `False` em `Python`? Como variável?

Comment: O python implementa dois conceitos essenciais, Espaço dos Nomes e Espaço dos Objectos. O que acontece nesse caso é que modificou o valor do objecto True/False logo alterou o Objecto no Espaço dos Objectos. Assim quando criar uma variavel que utilize esse objecto, a variavel irá utilizar o valor novo e não o original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Por que no Python é possível fazer isso?

Porque não são palavras reservadas, como no PHP ou em outras linguagens. [São variáveis de escopo com valores definidos](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html) (a documentação coloca a palavra "constant", mas na verdade você pode ter variáveis com os nomes `True` e `False`).

## Como é tratado `False` em Python? Como variável?

`False` em Python é equivalente ao inteiro 0, e `True`, ao inteiro 1:

```
int(False)
=> 0
int(True)
=> 1
```

## Adendo: Não vale para qualquer Python

Isto vale apenas para o Python 2. Para o Python 3, ocorre o seguinte:

```
PS C:\Users\lsanches> python
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> True = False
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to keyword
```

Comment: Obrigado pela Informação do `Python 3`.